# Why do we use multiplication for dot product normalization?

Tags: inner-products

The dot product formula is

$a \cdot b = \lvert a \rvert \lvert b \rvert \cos (\theta)$

This is the projection of $a$ onto $b$ scaled by $b$. Scaling by $b$ normalizes such that the magnitudes and not just the angle are taken into consideration when measuring vector alignment.

My question is about why we scale by $b$ for normalization instead of say, adding by $b$
where the dot product would be defined by...

$a \cdot b = \lvert a \rvert \cos (\theta) + \lvert b \rvert$

Wouldn't this be an equally effective means of normalization when measuring the similarity of two vectors? Is there something about scaling the quantity that is better for normalization?

Answer (score 2):

Several reasons.

The main reason is that in linear algebra you want to use the dot product to *define* the angle, not the other way around. With your definition the angle between $a$ and $b$ would change when you doubled the length of $b$.

Algebraically, your definition destroys important properties of the dot product. Compare what it does to what it should do with $a \cdot (b+c)$ and $a \cdot b + a \cdot c$.